# Need to replace repeating string with single instance

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Ok so I am taking a string, querying a database and then must provide a URL back to the page. There are multiple special characters in the input and I am stripping all special characters and spaces out using the following code and replacing with HTML "%25" so that my legacy system correctly searches for the value needed. What I need to do however is cut down the number of "%25" that show up.

My current code would replace something like

"Hello. / there Wilbur" with "Hello%25%25%25%25there%25Wilbur"

but I would like it to return

"Hello%25there%25Wilbur"

replacing multiples of the "%25" with only one instance

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '%25', $string); // Replaces special chars.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `+` after selecting a *non-alphanumeric* character.

```
$string = "Hello. / there Wilbur";
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);

// Just add a '+'. It will remove one or more consecutive instances of illegal
// characters with '%25'
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', '%25', $string);
```

Sample input: `Hello. / there Wilbur`

Sample output: `Hello%25there%25Wilbur`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
while (strpos('%25%25', $str) !== false)
    $str = str_replace('%25%25', '%25', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using a regexp:

`preg_replace('#((?:\%25){2,})#', '%25', $string_to_replace_in)`

No looping using a while, so the more consecutive '%25', the faster `preg_replace` is against a `while`.

Cf PHP doc:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php